# Is there a default version of `clone` in java?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a class called person

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int    age;
    ...
}
```

If I do not manually implement `clone` myself. What happens when I call `Person.clone()`? I heard from someone that Java will just do a "default" clone - where it deep copies all **primitive** data type attributes of the class. Is this true?

Comment: How about testing it? Or reading the javadoc of Object.clone()? Note that since there is no clone() method defined, the code trying to call clone() won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

It does what the [`Object.clone` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) says it does:

> The method `clone` for class `Object` performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown.

...so that's what `clone` on an instance of your `Person` class would do. If you added `implements Cloneable` to your class, then:

> ...Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

---

Side note: You've said

> What happens when I call `Person.clone()`?

I've assumed above you meant `Person p = new Person(/*...*/); Person p2 = p.clone();` instead of actually `Person.clone()`. `Person.clone()` won't compile, you have no `static` `clone` method on the class.

Answer (score -1):

My answer: do not use cloning. See the remark of [Josua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) in 2001 (yes, 16 years ago):

> The clone facility suffers from serious design flaws. [...] At this point, the clone facility is of very limited utility, so it is not clear that it is worth putting band aids on it. The best policy is generally not to use it.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4220218

Answer (score -1):

You can look at the documentation for [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> The method `clone` for class `Object` performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown.

Assuming, you implemented the cloneable interface. For example;

```
public class Person implements Cloneable {

String name;
int age;

 public Person clone() {
     return this;
 }
}
```

> Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. **Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.**

```
    Person p = new Person();
    Person p2 = p.clone();

    System.out.println(p2.name); // null
    System.out.print(p2.age); // 0
```

**Output:** will be default values.